# Exclude text labels on horizontal axis of Excel chart if no data for that particular label

Tags: excel

In a nutshell, x-axis categories are text (survey location ID #s) and the y-axis is numeric (nutrient concentration value).  There are no data for some of the survey locations so I want to exclude those particular stations from the graph.

The fixes I've seen are for small data sets but I'm subsetting from a larger dataset.  There has to be a simpler way to fix this than copying and pasting the data every time I need to do a different graph.

Help!

Comment: Why not filter out the rows with no data?

Comment: I found the easy fix... filter the data to exclude #N/A but then have to either copy that subset and use it or save your graph as a PDF so that it won't change when the filter is removed.  Crude but it'll do for now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.